# How may I align a mathematical statement and a few words straight of the following?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I would like to have the words 'to mean' and the following mathematical statement to be on the same straight line. Thank you very much!

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{flalign*}
    3=+1+1+1
    \end{flalign*}
    to mean
    \begin{flalign*}
    (+1+1+1)=+1+1+1,
    \end{flalign*}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: put `\text{to mean}` inside the `flalign`.

Comment: I want the words 'to mean' be on the left-hand side corner and the mathematical statement on the centre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
&3=+1+1+1   & \\
\intertext{to mean}
&(+1+1+1)=+1+1+1,&
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image: alignment]

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I wanted for I did not know how to convert my thought into words. Thank you so very much, Ian! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you want the original version or the edited version? I thought I had misinterpreted your question and changed the answer.

Comment: Oh, could you please be kind enough to post the 'original version'? I wanted exactly that. :) I appreciate if you could post the first one.

Comment: @NisalKevinKotinkaduwa --- done.

Comment: Of course using `flalign` is wrong; if left aligned equation are desired, the `fleqn` option should be given and then the indentation can be set by giving a new value to `\mathindent`.

Answer (score 3):

your code should be

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
3 &=+1+1+1   \\
\intertext{to mean}\\
(+1+1+1) &=+1+1+1,
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: intertextalign]

Comment: In doing so, this allows the two equations to be horizontally aligned. I could clearly use this because it would be much neater.
Could you shift the second equation so that it would be on the same straight line with the words 'to mean'? 
Is it possible to make that change?

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
3 =+1+1+1 & \qquad \quad to~{} mean & (+1+1+1) =+1+1+1,
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: intertextalign1]

Comment: Sir Murugan,
Thank you very much for devoting your precious time on this problem. But this is not what I meant. 
This is what I want; I do not want a VERTICAL space between the words 'to mean' and the SECOND equation. First equation is PERFECT. Two equations are aligned and that is also perfect. 
Only thing I need is 'to mean' and the second equation should be in the same line without altering the first one.

Comment: you should not typeset text in math mode, the font family and kerning are wrong. Use `\text{to mean}`